# Strange ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting random exception caused by ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig().

I don't have exact message, since our server is pt-BR, so error message is translated.

I know that this error can be thrown if user puts malicious code in input, ie example. But it's not case here.

I'm getting this one, requesting some images. Below some info from elmah.

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    GbPlugin
PATH_INFO:          /Content/images/BannerWelcome.jpg?1110311762734
PATH_TRANSLATED:    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\images\BannerWelcome.jpg?1110311762734
REQUEST_METHOD:     GET
SCRIPT_NAME:        /Content/images/BannerWelcome.jpg?1110311762734
```

Application is ASP.NET MVC 3, running on Windows 2008, IIS 7.5

**EDIT:**

Exception message in pt-BR:

```
System.Web.HttpException
Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Path foi detectado no cliente (?).

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Path foi detectado no cliente (?).
   em System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   em System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

**EDIT:**

Exception message in English: "A potentially dangerous value was detected from the client Request.Path"

**EDIT 2:**

I can't reproduce this error. As I know it is just in request to this image.

Comment: @Brad Wilson, last night I saw that you post a comment, but it is not available any more and I don't remember it.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with requests for images since those requests are (typically) handled by IIS and don't make it to your app.

Comment: You might want to look in your IIS log files and see if there are requests that are coming with invalid characters. From your message it seems that there is a request with a question mark in the middle of it.

Comment: @Hector those exception are handled by elmah, so my application are receiving that request. (Sorry my poor/bad english).

Comment: I would still double check with IIS logs. The message is pretty clear that there is an invalid question mark in the request (even though ELMAH is not showing it.) You could try to replicate the problem by embedding a question mark in the middle of a URL and see how ELMAH is logging it. (e.g. http://yoursite/path/yyy?zzz/?a=1)

Answer (score 6):

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

does not work in MVC3.

1) You have to explicitly put [ValidateRequest(false)] on each controller or action

2) If you use .NET4 this is not sufficient as there is a "bug/feature" in .NET4 which prevent [ValidateInput(false)] to work. 
You have to also disable requestPathInvalidCharacters,validateRequest and requestFiltering by using requestValidationMode of 2.0 :

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

Comment: Option 1 I think will not work since this error is on static file.

Comment: @Zote this error is a .NET error. That mean in his configuration .jpg files are processed through the asp.net pipeline.

Comment: ok, I know that. But in my web.config have something redirecting it to get processed by ASP.NET. Do you know how can I change it?

Answer (score 3):

I made three changes to solve this issue:

1)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
     </system.web>
```

2)

```
<system.webServer>      
    <security>  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" /> </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

3)     `<pages validateRequest="false" />`